# Excel file not opening in Jupyter lab and jupyter notebook

Tags: excel, jupyter-notebook

[image]

I could not open my excel file in jupter lab

Also when i tried to open file in jupyter notebook using dataframe its showing file not found.

Comment: DId converting it to csv work?

Answer (score 0):

Open it using excel and save it as a csv file. Then you can open the file. The excel format is not supported to jupyter lab that's why it is not opening. You have to convert it to UTF-8 comma delimited format to be able to read in jupyter lab

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using a 3rd party plugin such as this one to view .xlsx files:

https://github.com/quigleyj97/jupyterlab-spreadsheet

Installing is simple:

```sh
jupyter labextension install jupyterlab-spreadsheet
```

Then refresh/reload the JupyterLab browser window

Comment: When I'm trying to install the extension, the cmd is throwing the following error message:
`An error occured.
ValueError: Please install Node.js and npm before continuing installation. You may be able to install Node.js from your package manager, from conda, or directly from the Node.js website (https://nodejs.org).
See the log file for details:  C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\jupyterlab-debug-k4rmu__d.log`

Comment: Oh, I guess there is a dependency on node.js for this (or maybe all?) jupyter lab extensions. That surprises me a little, as I thought it was just a web js plugin and wouldn't need node.js (only for development and building, potentially). Anyway, I have node.js installed as I use it for numerous things. So, I guess you could download it from nodejs.org or you could create an issue on that guy's GitHub linked above.

Comment: Thinking a bit more about it, I guess jupyter might be using npm (node package manager) to manage (and maybe node to build) the extensions - that would make sense.